# npm install -g is copying all my source code to the prefix folder (Windows)

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm building a .NET Web Application and using NodeJS for a bunch of build tasks (minification, bundling, unit tests, etc).

My problem is that when I run the following from my source code folder:

- npm install -g

It not only checks and installs all of the node packages (great!) .. but it also copies the ENTIRE source code folder over to my global node_modules folder (.cs, .sln, bin folders .. the lot ... not so great!)

Is there any way of stopping it from doing this?

*Note - I've redirected the npm and cache folders to a separate path using:*

- npm config set prefix e:\npm-repo\npm --global
- npm config set cache e:\npm-repo\cache --global

Answer (score 0):

This is how `npm install -g` works.

You can try `npm install` if you want to install only the dependencies from package.json locally.

Comment: I thought it should copy the NPM packages .. not my .NET source code?